# Enabling Mink Extension in Behat

Tags: bdd, behat, mink

I'm trying to add the Mink extension to Behat. I've installed Behat, Mink and Mink-Extension through composer. However, now I'm having trouble with enabling the extension. Here is my `behat.yml`:

```
default:
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
        base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
        goutte: ~
        selenium2: ~
```

Here is my example test:

```
Feature: New
    In order to test Behat
    As a developer
    I need to test that Mink Extension works

    Scenario:
        Given I am on the homepage
```

When I run Behat, I get this output:

```
Feature: New
  In order to test Behat
  As a developer
  I need to test that Mink Extension works

  Scenario:                    # features/new.feature:6
    Given I am on the homepage # FeatureContext::iAmOnHomepage()
    Mink instance has not been set on Mink context class. Have you enabled the Mink Extension? (RuntimeException)

--- Failed scenarios:

features/new.feature:6

1 scenario (1 failed)
1 step (1 failed)
0m0.02s (11.86Mb)
```

So I searched for 'Mink instance has not been set on Mink context class. Have you enabled the Mink Extension? (RuntimeException)' and got no decent results. What do I need to do to enable the extension?

Comment: is your FeatureContext class extending MinkContext class (Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default profile and extensions are not aligned properly, try align document according to yml markup

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
```

For more information check [behat extension docs](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/guides/7.config.html#extensions)